# RadCombobox Value on Select vs Expand

Tags: wpf, telerik, radcombobox

I have combobox with values 0, 1, 2. When user expand the combobox to select the value, I want to show Text of the value as  0 - Bad, 1 - Average, 2 - Good.

But when user select the value, I want to display the value only.

How can I do this ? Here is my Code

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Flags}"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding FlagId,Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectedValuePath="Id"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Id">               
 </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to switch DisplayMemberPath="Id" to some property of the type Flags is, that displays the ID and description in the format you want.

Comment: Yes I gave the DisplayMemberPath as Name which contains "0 - Bad" as string. But my scenario is different. I don't want that string to display when they select. Users want to see 0 only

Comment: looks like a solution. Will look into it. Thanks!